# React admin Filter query inside useGetList

Tags: react-admin

[image]

I want to filter the response with selected project_id. For that I have implemented a filter in

```
  const { data } = useGetList("project_skill_requirement", {
    project_id: projectId,
  });
```

where projectId is selected project id ("5b99808c-6059-4bfa-96ac-2fa74c66af31").

so that I will get the response of selected project.But instead of that it showing all the project list shown in the picture.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter you **response**, apply the filter on the `data` you received like

```
const { data } = useGetList("project_skill_requirement");
const projects = data.filter(({project_id}) => project_id === projectId);
```

If you want to filter on request, your payload seems good, look at the network request to see if your filter is properly applied.